# How to use a member of a structure defined by a compound literal?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, structure, compound-literals

I´ve found this piece of code, which uses a pointer to a structure made by a compound literal:

```
int main()
{
   struct s {int i; int x;} *p;
   int j = 0;

   p = &((struct s){ j++ });
}
```

My questions are:

- How is `j++` a valid expression for modifying `i` and/or `x` and to what it get evaluated?
- And how can I access the member `i` or `x`? Pointer offsets of `p`?

Comment: `j++` is initializing member `i` with it's "previous" value (which is 0) and post-incremented. The other members are initialized with zeros. `p->i` `p->x` are to access the members.

Comment: Re “I´ve found this piece of code”: When you find a piece of code lying on the street, you should leave it there and not touch it. You do not know where it has been. Quite often, it is pretty icky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a compound literal, any unspecified members get default-initialized, just like an initializer list for an object. So

```
(struct s){ j++ })
```

is equivalent to

```
(struct s){ j++, 0 })
```

`j++` is the old value of `j` before `j` is incremented, just as in any other assignment. So this will set `p->i = 0` and `j = 1`.

You can access the members using pointer dereferencing.

```
int x = p->x;
int i = p->i;
```

Comment: The old value is `0`, it gets assigned to the struct member. Then the increment happens, so `j == 1` afterwards.